# How get Mac Music to update its library data based on my folder structure

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, music.app

I started my shift towards apple products over 17 years ago when I purchased my first iPod (yes the click wheels one :-)).
I started by using iTunes software for managing my music library, then I bought my first iPhone then switched to using mac book pro.

Now, over all these jumps i moved my library from one computer to another, letting iTunes manage files. Then came Mac Music... My current situation is that I have all my music in the `/Users/<user>/Music` folder but, within this folder they are all over the place.

```
/Users/<user>/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music
/Users/<user>/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Music
/Users/<user>/Music/Music/Media.localized/Music (What does '.localized' mean?)
```

I tried [consolidating](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/music/mus69248042d/mac) the library but I can still see many files/folder outside the media folder.

I have manually moved the music files to the media folder now but, **How do I get Mac Music to change the location of the files, in its library, based on what is on the hard drive?**

Any suggestions/help will be much appreciated.